# Calling moveCamera not trigger setOnCameraMoveListener on map android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to perform some action, when `setOnCameraMoveListener` is called in map view. So i'm using the below line of code inside `onClusterClick` method

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), width, height, 60));
```

But this will not trigger `setOnCameraMoveListener`.

My `build.gradle` file contain the below dependency.

```
 compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
```

Could you please give me any idea to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to use this `setOnCameraChangeListener`?

Comment: @jay droider yes. but this method gets deprecated in compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'

Comment: Change you *dependency* to this `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0` and try again. Make sure you have updated *google play services* to latest version in your *sdk*.

Comment: @jay droider, Hi i have checked before post this question. when i use compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3', setOnCameraChangeListener will works for me. But i want to know. why setOnCameraMoveListener method is not called when using moveCamera method?

Comment: @jay droider. okay i will check and let you know. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I have not gone through details using this but as of i have bit idea with this method so i have suggested . Best luck.